# Shinny: Cannot open shapefile from inputfile with leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, rgdal

I am new with shinny and I would like to do the simple task of:

1. input a shapefile from my computer
2. open it with leaflet or mapview.

But I am getting the message "`Warning: Error in ogrListLayers: Cannot open data source`"

Below are the codes:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
#### UI ####
ui<-fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Input",
             fileInput("Map_01", "Shapefile - MAP",
                       accept = c(".shp","shp"), multiple=FALSE)
    ),
    tabPanel("Map",
             mainPanel(
               leafletOutput("mapplot")
             )
    )
  )
)
#### SERVER ####
server<-function(input,output){
  map <- reactive({
      mapview(readOGR(input$Map_01$datapath))
    })
  output$mapplot <-renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(map())
    })

}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Toydata:

```
#Download the shapefiles
download.file("http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip" ,destfile="world_shape_file.zip")
system("unzip world_shape_file.zip")
inputfile<-readOGR("./TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")
```

Comment: Does it work outside shiny ?

Comment: Yes it does. Both with leaftlet and mapview.

Comment: `input$Map_01$datapath` is `NULL` when the app starts. Isn't it the problem ? You should add `req(input$Map_01)` just before `mapview(readOGR(input$Map_01$datapath))`.

Comment: Just tried with your sugestion but still got the same error

Comment: I read [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-solve-this-error-when-i-read-shp-file/19832) that *A shapefile requires the .shp as well as the .shx and .dbf files*.

Comment: I think you need `mapview(readOGR(input$Map_01$datapath))@map` to access the leaflet widget in mapview